# Extract string between first and last _

Tags: r, regex, string, character, gsub

Although I have searched through stackoverflow looking for various gsub answers, I cannot find the code to apply to the data I have. I want to create a new column which extracts all letters between the first and last underscores.

```
Test <- as.data.frame(c("A_YES_X","A_Yes_YES_X"))
colnames(Test)[1] <- "test"
```

So in the example above, this would be the output I would need.

```
Test$Output <- c("YES","Yes_YES")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
x <- c("A_YES_X","A_Yes_YES_X")
stringi::stri_extract(x, regex = '(?<=_).*(?=_)')
#[1] "YES"     "Yes_YES"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find the part of your string that is everything before the first _ (including it) using `^[^_]*_`, and the part after the last _ (including  it) using `_[^_]*$`. You can remove them using `gsub`:

```
gsub("_[^_]*$|^[^_]*_","",test,perl=T)
[1] "YES"     "Yes_YES"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with extracting only captured pattern "one or more characters (.+) between first and last _ (well explained by @Lamia).

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("A_YES_X","A_Yes_YES_X")
str_match(x,"^[^_]*_(.+)_[^_]*$")[,2]
```